# ReactJS map through an array with objects

Tags: reactjs

I have that part of code

```
const links = [
  {
    name: 'How it works',
    ref: '/'
  },
  {
    name: 'Calendar',
    ref: 'calendar'
  },
  {
    name: 'Contact me',
    ref: 'contact'
  }
];

const renderLinks = links.map((link, index) =>
  <li className="nav-item active" key={index}>
    <a className="nav-link" href={link.ref || "#"}>
      {link.name}
    </a>
  </li>
);
```

However when I try to render it an error is thrown.

```
render() {
    return (
      {renderLinks}
    );
  }
```

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {renderLinks}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use
>   an array instead.

As I think, I have to got an array but React thinks there is an object.

Comment: `return renderLinks;`

Comment: @dfsq wow... Thanks a lot. Solved my problem. Feel free to post an answer I'll check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React thinks this is an object because you indeed provided an object. This is what it is if you write it without shortcut property notation:

```
render() {
  return {
    renderLinks: renderLinks
  );
}
```

Just return `renderLinks` directly without `{ }`:

```
render() {    
  return renderLinks;
}
```